# Is it possible to derive a non-mass gap from the Yang-Mills action?

Tags: mass, gauge-theory, action, yang-mills, confinement

The action:

$$J=∫Tr(F∧⋆F).$$

Is it possible to find the non-mass gap property from the Yang mills action? If so, how?

Comment: Lattice computations show that a mass gap exists. So, what do you mean by a "non-mass gap property"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "non-mass gap property", but *any* general and rigorous statement about the (non-)existence of mass gaps in Yang-Mills would be at least a partial solution to one of the unsolved [millenium problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap)...